# Regarding return value of python select.select call

Tags: python, linux, sockets, select

In python's SocketServer.py code, I find the following code.

```
r, w, e = _eintr_retry(select.select, [self], [], [], poll_interval)
if self in r:
    self._handle_request_noblock()
```

Is the above if statement necessary?  Since only "self" is being passed to select call, I do not expect other file descriptor to be present in the returned list of file descriptor.

The reason I am asking this is, should I have to follow the above style or something like the following would be enough?

```
r, w, e = select.select( [self], [], [], poll_interval)
if  r:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if r:
```

is not the same as

```
if self in r:
```

You can read on [`select.select`](http://devdocs.io/python2/library/select#select.select) documentation:

> Empty sequences are allowed, but acceptance of three empty sequences
>   is platform-dependent.
>
> [...]
>
> The return value is a triple of lists of objects that are ready:
>   subsets of the first three arguments. **When the time-out is reached
>   without a file descriptor becoming ready, three empty lists are
>   returned**.

Since, in the module, a variable `poll_interval` is being passed to the function, you may get a case when empty lists are returned. An empty list will pass the simple `if r:` check!